# Merge the content of two file alternatively in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two file:

**File1:**

```
  0: void apple.<init>() 
  1: void apple.main(java.lang.String[])
```

**File2:**

```
DEX CODE:
      0x0000: 7010 0300 0000            | invoke-direct {v0}, void 
      java.lang.Object.<init>() // method@3
      0x0003: 0e00                      | return-void
DEX CODE:
      0x0000: 1200                      | const/4 v0, #+0
      0x0001: 1301 6400                 | const/16 v1, #+100
      0x0003: 2313 0a00                 | new-array v3, v1, int[] // type@10
```

How I could merge the content alternatively in bash script like:

```
0: void apple.<init>() 
DEX CODE:
      0x0000: 7010 0300 0000            | invoke-direct {v0}, void 
      java.lang.Object.<init>() // method@3
      0x0003: 0e00                      | return-void

1: void apple.main(java.lang.String[])
DEX CODE:
      0x0000: 1200                      | const/4 v0, #+0
      0x0001: 1301 6400                 | const/16 v1, #+100
      0x0003: 2313 0a00                 | new-array v3, v1, int[] // type@10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Always add your efforts which you have in order to solve your problems on SO in code tags.

Comment: What is the structure of the file 2 (i.e. how to decide whether the new entry in file 2 started)? Is it determined by the `DEX CODE:` line?

Comment: @JindraHelcl, Yes it always determined and start by the DEX CODE: .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} /^DEX/{$0=a[++count] ORS $0} 1' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

In case you want to save output into anyone of Input_file(s) then use following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} /^DEX/{$0=a[++count] ORS $0} 1'  Input_file1 Input_file2 > temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file2
```

Comment: It only prints file2 content , not merging.

Comment: @Arya, do you want to save final output into Input_file2 itself?

Comment: I tried in redirecting into  another file , but the content has not merged, only showing the content of file2

Comment: @Arya, is your Input_file1 is same as shown or different? I considered that there are NO spaces in starting of it(though it shouldn't affect anything), can you also check about control M characters in it by doing `cat -v Input_file1` once too?

Comment: My Input file `file1` is: `0: void apple.<init>() (dex_method_idx=0)
  1: void apple.main(java.lang.String[]) (dex_method_idx=1)
`

Comment: And it is also having two space from starting

Comment: @Arya, if your Input_flle2 have `DEX` string it should and work and I tested it successfully too. Did you check about control M characters in your file once since it is working fine for me.

Comment: I could not see any control M character in my file

Comment: @Arya, see my EDIT and make sure you are running command in same mode(we have to put name of file1 and then file2 in command) it works perfectly fine for me, let me know?

Comment: It is working, problem was my file start with spaces in each line, so I removed leading spaces, followed above step. Thanks!!